# "Worksheet range names does not exist" KeyError in openpyxl

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

Let me preface this by saying I have tried looking for, and cannot seem to find a similar situation so please don't be too upset if this seems familiar to you. I am using **Python 2.7** and **openpyxl version 2.2.5** (I need to use 2.7, and used an older module for other reasons.)

I am new to Python and read/write code in general, so I'm testing this on the command line before I implement it:

1. I created a file, `foo.xlsx` in the Python27 file directory with some values that I manually entered via Excel.
2. I then used this simple code on the Python command line to test my code

   ```
   from openpyxl import load_workbook
   wb = load_workbook('foo.xlsx')
   sheet_ranges = wb['range names']
   ```

It then resulted in the following error:

> File "C:\Python27\lib\openpyxl\workbook.workbook.py", line 233 in **getitem**
>           raise KeyError("Worksheet {0} does not exist.".format(key))
>   KeyError: 'Worksheet sheet range names does not exist'

So I thought it had something to do with not importing the entire openpyxl module. I proceeded to do that and run the whole process but it resulted in the same error.

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong/how to solve this?

Additional information:

- I had successfully written to an empty file before, and then read the values. This gave me the right values for everything EXCEPT what I had written in manually via Excel- the cells that had manual input returned None or Nonetype. The issue seems to be with cells with manual input.
- I did hit save on the file before accessing it don't worry

This was in the same directory so I know that it wasn't a matter of location.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following command does not make sense:

```
sheet_ranges = wb['range names']
```

Normally you open a workbook and then access one of the worksheets, the following gives you some examples on how this can be done:

```
import openpyxl 

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'input.xlsx')

# To display all of the available worksheet names
sheets = wb.sheetnames
print sheets

# To work with the first sheet (by name)
ws = wb[sheets[0]]
print ws['A1'].value

# To work with the active sheet
ws = wb.active
print ws['A1'].value

# To work with the active sheet (alternative method)
ws = wb.get_active_sheet()
print ws['A1'].value
```

If you want to display any named range in the workbook, you can do the following:

```
print wb.get_named_ranges()
```

Comment: Hi Martin,

    ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheets[0])

 is returning the same error. the code I wrote does the same thing, except I know the name of the sheet, hence it assigns the sheet called range names.
It said that the worksheet Sheet1 does not exist

Comment: `ws = wb.active` is the usual way to work with an existing worksheet, have you tried that?

Comment: To anyone reading this answer:
' ws = wb.active' 
used manually entered data in the sheet, the other method(recommended by [link](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.2/usage.html))
returned Nonetypes for manual inputs.

Comment: I advise against using `wb.get_named_ranges()` as it is essentially an internal function.

Comment: @CharlieClark OP did specify Python 2.7

Comment: Noted, and appreciated.

Comment: @MartinEvans I know that Python 2.7 was specified but it isn't actually relevant to the question: accessing the ranges.

Comment: Thank you Martin for your help.   The original code R. Joseph posted comes from the openpyxl tutorial which is odd: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook .   Note: I think there is a typo in your example ws = wb.[sheets[0]] should be ws = wb[sheets[0]] (without the period).    But very useful.  Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure what it is you need to do, but to read Excel spreadsheets into python, I usually use xlrd (which to me was easier to get use to). See example:

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(in_fname)
worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
```

To write to Excel spreadsheets, I use xlsxwriter:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(out_fname)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('spreadsheet_name')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Should I just scrap openpyxl? I've been reading that openpyxl was the best module to use to manipulate xlsx files. 
Will this read data manually entered into the spreadsheet?

Comment: xlrd and xlsxwriter are both fine libraries but openpyxl is currently the only Python library that lets you edit XLSX files.